# Using the symbol of the system of equations

Tags: equation-solving, syntax, symbols, built-in-symbols, education

**Part 1**

I'd like to know how to use the symbol of system of equations (left curly braces). I tried the following code:

[image]

**Part 2**

How can I add a third equation?

Comment: You have already asked this question. I already answered you in the comment. You should make your previous question more precise. For this reason, I vote to close this question since it is the second question on the same subject.

Comment: Hello @user64494 this new question is different; the question you cited is about how to write the symbol, instead this question is about how to use the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

```
eqns = {x + y + z == 1, x - 2 y + 4 z == 2, x + y == 1};

Grid[{
  {Style["{", 18*Length@eqns, Gray], First@eqns},
  Sequence @@ ({SpanFromAbove, #} & /@ (Rest@eqns))}, 
 Alignment -> {{Right, "=="}, Center}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @BobHanlon thank you for your answer. My goal is to use the left curly bracket in the InputForm, not only in the output. See the figure please (In[1]:). Can you tell me how to use it please?